# How can I let the user add an attachment to my app like a pdf or jpg and then how can I store it in my Realm Database?

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, attachment

Here is my code for my object that I am storing in Realm Database

```
class Accomp2: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var date: Date!
    @objc dynamic var month:String = ""
    required init() {
    }
    @objc dynamic var body:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var type:String = "Professional"
    @objc dynamic var identifier:String = ""
}
```

I want to be able to store the attachment in a variable called `attachment`, but I am not sure what type of variable that is.

With the object, I want to be able to show this attachment on a view controller as a picture.

If this is not possible with Realm Database, is there another way to store attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Realm property Cheat Sheet](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-cheatsheet)

What you want is the NSData() e.g. Swift Data() object - he's some simple code as a conceptual example.

```
let url = //your file
let myData = Data(contentsOf: url) //please handle the optional correctly

class Accomp2: Object {
   @objc dynamic var acc_id = UUID().uuidString
   @objc dynamic var name = ""
   @objc dynamic var value = Data()
}

let x = Accomp2()
x.name = "Some name"
x.value = myData
```

IMPORTANT!

While you *can* do this, you probably shouldn't.

Realm is not well suited for handling documents within objects. If it's a thumbnail or a couple hundred kb, it will be ok. But PDF's can get HUGE and Realm is not the right solution.

You should store files in another source that's designed for storing files - Firebase [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) is one such option and then store the URL to the file within your Realm object.